# How to pass in timeout for cucumber command as in start_test_server_in_background(:timeout => 30)

Tags: ios, cucumber, calabash, calabash-ios

After digging around for a few days for the launch issue, I found out if I use

`start_test_server_in_background(:timeout => 300)`

the app will be fully launched successfully.

So for calabash command, the question become, how to pass in the timeout for cucumber command line?

I tried the following for cucumber version 0.9.167 and it's not working.

`$ CONNECT_TIMEOUT=300 DEBUG=1 CALABASH_FULL_CONSOLE_OUTPUT=1 cucumber`

Comment: We need more details. Please see this calabash-ios topic - http://goo.gl/yQi0bE - and update your question.  And I think you cross posted. -1 to you if did.

Comment: @jmoody yes, I may cross post it since not all ppl are living in the same universe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CONNECT_TIMEOUT` <== controls how long to wait for the *server* to respond to an http request not how long it wait for a launch.

Update your `features/support/01_launch.rb` to use:

`Calabash::Cucumber::Launcher.relaunch({:timeout => 300})`

I am suspicious that it takes more than 30s to launch your app.

If at all possible update to latest version of calabash.

UPDATE: The calabash environment docs have been posted.

http://calabashapi.xamarin.com/ios/

Beware of tweaking the variables in the Developer section.