# How to tell Calabash to NOT timeout while the simulator... slowly... grinds into motion?

Tags: calabash, calabash-ios

*Context*

I have a Mac Mini running Xcode, and a series of Cucumber tests ran with Calabash.

*Issue*

They fail because the simulator takes very long (possibly 50 seconds) to get up and running. I've tried to pass `timeout` launch options (by passing them in front of my call as per the documentation) but I'm still failing, and I haven't either understood yet how to use launch options in `calabash-ios console` mode.

I'm reading through the source in the hope of finding something not documented [here](https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/blob/0a16aaeed784b45479580ebc88fb5eeeab82cac1/calabash-cucumber/ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLES.md).

I actually get no progress from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24075107/how-to-pass-in-timeout-for-cucumber-command-as-in-start-test-server-in-backgroun):

```
calabash-ios console
> Running irb...
> irb(main):001:0> start_test_server_in_background(:timeout => 6000)
> RunLoop::Xcrun::TimeoutError: Xcrun timed out after 30.30 seconds executing
> xcrun instruments -s templates
> with a timeout of 30
```

*Can I disable the launch timeout entirely, and **how** would I do that (save editing the calabash source...)?*

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24075107/how-to-pass-in-timeout-for-cucumber-command-as-in-start-test-server-in-backgroun  As for adding launch options, you put them in front like this "DEVICE_TARGET='iPhone 6 (9.1)' DEBUG=1 calabash-ios console". That also took me some time and help to figure out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not quite obvious, but there is a way. From [xcrun.rb](https://github.com/calabash/run_loop/blob/9d10354b34eec5446ed3d8d19252435411cd302e/lib/run_loop/xcrun.rb#L6) (which is actually in the [run_loop](https://github.com/calabash/run_loop) gem),

```
# You can override these values if they do not work in your environment.
#
# For cucumber users, the best place to override would be in your
# features/support/env.rb.
#
# For example:
#
# RunLoop::Xcrun::DEFAULT_OPTIONS[:timeout] = 60
```

Let me know if that doesn't work for you.

As far as disabling it altogether, I think it's easier to just use a huge value for the timeout. Keep in mind though, the timeouts are there for a reason. If your simulator is actually stuck and unable to launch for some reason, it's reasonable to have some timeout to bail.

Comment: It's really not stuck but unbearably slow (the machine is making me go insane launching the simulator manually, I'm waiting for my company to order a new machine...). You are right about using huge values, I'll try your technique and report back!

Comment: @Kheldar the answer to 'Can I disable the launch timeout entirely [without modifying calabash source]' is no. See https://github.com/calabash/run_loop/blob/ef787180a27903ea55c50467e7b90821d0c7a3a2/lib/run_loop/device.rb#L405  I don't think it would be too hard to modify if you were up for making a fork of the repo, but in general a large timeout would be easier.

Answer (score 2):

> unbearably slow

You have to update to a new machine.  I recommend a SSD drive - it will really speed up your simulator tests.

In addition to `RunLoop::Xcrun::DEFAULT_OPTIONS[:timeout]` see [RunLoop::CoreSimulator::DEFAULT_OPTIONS](https://github.com/calabash/run_loop/blob/develop/lib/run_loop/core_simulator.rb#L15).

```
  # These options control various aspects of an app's life cycle on the iOS
  # Simulator.
  #
  # You can override these values if they do not work in your environment.
  #
  # For cucumber users, the best place to override would be in your
  # features/support/env.rb.
  #
  # For example:
  #
  # RunLoop::CoreSimulator::DEFAULT_OPTIONS[:install_app_timeout] = 60
  DEFAULT_OPTIONS = {
    # In most cases 30 seconds is a reasonable amount of time to wait for an
    # install.  When testing larger apps, on slow machines, or in CI, this
    # value may need to be higher.  120 is the default for CI.
    :install_app_timeout => RunLoop::Environment.ci? ? 120 : 30,
    :uninstall_app_timeout => RunLoop::Environment.ci? ? 120 : 30,
    :launch_app_timeout => RunLoop::Environment.ci? ? 120 : 30,
    :wait_for_state_timeout => RunLoop::Environment.ci? ? 120 : 30
  }
```

Comment: [Yes, I agree, I do need a new machine. Waiting for the proper department to provide.] Right now, I'm trying to find out how to send xcodebuild a -project option, because my team would like to run tests on several projects and platforms in a unified build system. Is that possible?

Comment: Using xcodebuild is a separate question.  Please don't ask questions about other topics in comments - ask a new question.  Look at the Makefile and bin/make scripts in these projects https://github.com/calabash/ios-smoke-test-app/tree/master/CalSmokeApp | https://github.com/calabash/Permissions 100% possible.  100% recommended.